# Building package against older Rcpp version

Tags: r, package, rcpp, devtools

I'm writing an R package for simulations using Rcpp. Rcpp project setup has added my Rcpp version as dependendy `Rcpp (>= 1.0.9)`

A project partner who is trying to run the simulations has Rcpp version 1.0.8. I did not see anything in the release notes of Rcpp 1.0.9 that would suggest, that the package wouldn't build on version 1.0.8 but I would want to try to build it before changing the dependency.

Would the following work to test this:

1. install Rcpp 1.0.8 from the CRAN archive to a local library
2. add the local library as first entry to library paths with `.libPaths`
3. call `devtools::build`

Comment: Yes but you can also edit your DESCRIPTION file after the fact, edit it down to 1.0.8 and let your project partner try that.  If there are issues. ask to upgrade.  This just plain R and package management and nothing to do with Rcpp per se.  (See the file [NEWS](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/news.html) about what changed, the newer Rcpp is a little cleaner about its interfaces and the last point refers to that. Fuller details in the [ChangeLog](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/ChangeLog).)

Comment: Thank you. I was not sure if this is any different for packages, that are needed at build time only. It builds with 1.0.8, lets see what the project partner says.

Comment: Rcpp is not used at build time only.  It 'adds a dependency' which is resolved when the package using is attached (which is why it will likely still have an `Imports: Rcpp`).  And your project partner is less likely to run into an issue with 1.0.9 than with 1.0.8 (which may still work -- but _newer packages generally fix bugs older packages may exhibit_. It all depends.  Your overruling of a dependency is both _possible in the narrow sense_ and _possibly marginally more likely to exhibit an issue_.